# Google AutoML Importing text items very slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I'm importing text items to Google's AutoML.  Each row contains around 5000 characters and I'm adding 70K of these rows.  This is a multi-label data set.  There is no progress bar or indication of how long this process will take.  Its been running for a couple of hours.  Is there any way to calculate time remaining or total estimated time.  I'd like to add additional data sets, but I'm worried that this will be a very long process before the training even begins.  Any sort of formula to create even a semi-wild guess would be great.
-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible today, but I filed a feature request [[1]](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111861014) that you can follow for updates. I asked for both training and importing data, as for training it could be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried training with 50K records (~ 300 bytes/record) and the load took more than 20 mins after which I killed it. I retried with 1K, which ran for 20 mins and then emailed me an error message saying I had multiple labels per input (yes, so what? training data is going to have some of those) and I had >100 labels. I simplified the classification buckets and re-ran. It took another 20 mins and was successful. Then I ran 'training' which took 3 hours and billed me $11. That maps to $550 for 50K recs, assuming linear behavior. The prediction results were not bad for a first pass, but I got the feeling that it is throwing a super large neural net at the problem. Would help if they said what NN it was and its dimensions. They do say "beta" :)

Answer (score 0):

don't wast your time trying to using google for text classification. I am a GCP hard user but microsoft LUIS is far better, precise and so much faster that I can't believe that both products are trying to solve same problem.

Luis has a much better documentation, support more languages, has a much better test interface, way faster.. I don't know if is cheaper yet because the pricing model is different but we are willing to pay more.

Comment: I'm using it for patient chart notes.  50K+ records in the training set.  Takes a long time to train, but predicts quickly and accurate. I'm satisfied.  The cost so far has been covered by promotional credit.